Creating a vertex on an edge with a single click

Often times When I am modeling, I encounter a scenario where I need to create a vertex at a specific location. Until now I have solved this by "subdividing" the edge and sliding the vertex into place. Over the course of hours and hours though, this practice can get very old. I really would like to have the ability to simply click an edge and have a vertex be created exactly where I clicked. I would think the knife tool would have this functionality, but unfortunately if you click an edge once and then press "enter" it cancels the operation.
Is there any addon or method anybody knows to just easily create a vertex with one click?
PS I am aware of alt-V as well but it similarly requires sliding the vertex into place which I am trying to avoid.

I found a solution using the Half Knife addon. Initially I discounted this because I was not a huge fan of the changes made to the knife functionality in the addon, but you can change preferences in order to still keep the default knife tool, while gaining the ability to press ⇧ Shift + K and slice a vertex at the cursor.
